# Outlook Application_Quit Event Doesn't Fire

Tags: vba, outlook

I have an event in the ThisOutlookSession module:

```
Public Sub Application_Quit()
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim rootFolder As String
    Dim oFolder As Object
    Dim oFile As Object
    Dim filename As String
    Dim fullpath As String
    ...Procedure...
End Sub
```

When this triggers, it works correctly. However, the Quit event will not fire unless I have opened up the VBE editor during the session. For example, if I open Outlook and immediately close it, the _Quit event will not fire. If I then open Outlook again, open the editor, and then close Outlook, the _Quit event will fire as expected.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52614805/outlook-vba-application-startup-not-firing) for a similar issue- though I've tried everything listed there without success. Changing the Private/Public status of the event, restarting the PC- these don't seem to have any effect. I've added a blank Public _Startup event, which has also had no effect.

What the specific procedure is in the _Quit event is irrelevant- I've tried just having a simple Msgbox in there, and the same behavior is observed.

I'm in Outlook 2013 on Windows 10 Enterprise, Enable All Macros in the Trust center.

Any ideas at all would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I understand you tried the empty Application_Startup, have you tried putting executable code in it?  I am very curious if you experience the same problem if you initialized a class that exposed application events on startup, does the class trigger the quit event, what about the class terminate event?

Comment: I threw in a simple:  Debug.Print "This worked!" into the Application_Startup event.


This had no effect. The "This worked!" text did not appear in the Immediate pane on startup, and the _Close event still would not fire. So it seems the startup event is also not triggering in my case.

Comment: This is kind of a silly, but I have to ask, are you typing the procedure header or selecting it from the drop down list in the VBE?  If you're typing it, try removing the deleting/renaming the current event and add new one from the drop down.

Comment: Good thought, but I've found my issue. Turns out to have been an add-in I didn't know was installed causing the _Startup event not to fire. After removing that, _Startup ran fine, and I could use the `Explorer.Close` event to accomplish what I was after, as Dmitry recommended below.

Comment: @Darkwind I'm curious which add-in was preventing the _Startup event, in case I might have the same one. Thanks!

Comment: @vknowles IIRC it was the Hubspot CRM add-in.

Comment: @Darkwind Thanks. I don't have that one, but I suspect other add-ins might cause problems, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Outlook is doing a fast shutdown, `Application.Quit` won't fire.
The best you can do is `Explorer.Close` on the last visible `Explorer` object.