# Outlook doesn't see batch updated OTM file without manual intervention

Tags: vba, batch-file, outlook

I created an Outlook macro for numerous users.

To make installation process easier I made a batch script that closes Outlook, copies the OTM file from a shared drive to %appdata%\Microsoft\Outlook and opens Outlook again.

Usually Outlook doesn't see the macro after running the script. Users need to press alt+f11 (OTM project is in place) and restart Outlook. It seems opening the editor makes the macro available.

What should I do to make the macro work immediately after running the batch script?

Users have Outlook 2013 or Office 365.

Comment: Maybe try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62926453) about setting `"LoadMacroProviderOnBoot"=dword:00000001` under `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\<version>\Outlook` in the registry.

Comment: It seems that it solved my problem. Thanks!